# fs cannot find the file

Tags: meteor, fs

I'm running meteor on a codeanywhere container.
I want to read a file with fs (I have another container with node+express and I can use it fine there). The file is located next to the main.js script in the server folder.

In the main.js I'm trying to do this:

```
 console.log(process.cwd());
  console.log(path.resolve(__dirname));
  let filePath = path.join(__dirname,"History.txt")
  console.log(filePath);
  let value =  fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
```

I've tried the simple History.txt, ./History.txt, to run it with the full result of process.cwd, from the public folder... but all I get is:

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/server/History.txt'
```

process.cwd is:

```
/home/cabox/workspace/anaplus/.meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

__dirnam is:

```
/server
```

I cannot see what's wrong here

Comment: Where do you place the file in your local development folder structure?

Comment: oh my... I've added that small detail to  my question, thanks (in the server folder)

Comment: Is this a dynamically created file, or a static one?

Comment: @Eagle1 is this issue resolved?

Comment: no, I gave up, your solution was too complex for this which was a temporary  thing

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a top-level folder named `private` then it will be available under `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app` and you can then also obtain it using Assets: https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html